# Can Magnus Carlsen force draw (pun-intended) himself to victory?

Tags: world-championship, draw, carlsen, anand

So far `Carlsen` has a 2 game lead over `Anand` and there are only 4 games left.  At the strength of these players, can `Magnus` basically force his opponent into draws by playing certain openings or styles?  Can he force `Anand` into drawing the rest of the games to win the world championship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "basically". He cannot actually force a draw in any given game (otherwise he would have started doing it already, as soon as he won one game). However he can play drawish lines; the variation he went into in game 8, for example, is almost never lost by White at top levels.

It's going to be difficult for Carlsen to "force" a draw if Anand plays something sharp like the Dutch or Pirc. His optimal strategy is still pretty much to just continue to play good chess.

Comment: Maybe Basically wasn't the correct word, but you answered my question.  I guess the fact that he can play drawish lines as in game 8 which is almost never lost by white as you said means that his chances of drawing go up significantly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Carlsen certainly is going to be pretty comfortable for the rest of the games as white. He can choose lines that have a high drawing percentage.

I would expect Anand to start choosing more tactical lines as white and black. So far we've seen quite a bit of king pawn games, more specifically the Ruy Lopez. I wouldn't be surprised to see Anand break out a Sicilian or two in the coming games.

Comment: Yes, I think that has been a surprise that Anand keeps going back to the Ruy Lopez when it is not working for him.